# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Model.country is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```xml
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.country, Model.country)
```

```cs
public class Registration
{
    public List<SelectListItem> country { get; set; }

    public Registration()
    {            
        country = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "India" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "USA" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "UK" },            
        };
    }
}
```

I am trying to populate the `country` in `DropDownList` in view but I am get error. It is returning `Model.country` is `null`. Country list is not bound to country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following example.

The `Index` action method:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new Registration()
    {
        country = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "India" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "USA" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "UK" },
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

The `Index.cshtml` markup:

```html
@model Models.Registration
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.country.GetEnumerator().Current, Model.country, "-select a value-")
</div>
```

*I suppose you have an error in the view code that you don't included to the question.*